# Eigen c++ and intel mkl compilation error

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using the gsl library and eigen c++ library in a program. In order to increase the speed of it I am using also the MKL intel library. I was able to compile the program in Ubuntu 20.04 with g++ 9.3.0 following the instructions of Eigen documentation and the MKL linking advisor. However, when I tried to compile my program in another pc with xubuntu and g++ 10.03 I got the following error

```
In file included from /usr/include/mkl/mkl.h:31,
             from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/MKL_support.h:62,
             from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:47,
             from csbm_mu_parameter_mkl.cpp:17:
```

/usr/include/mkl/mkl_cblas.h:65:34: error: ‘CblasRowMajor’ conflicts with a previous declaration
65 | enum CBLAS_LAYOUT {CblasRowMajor=101, CblasColMajor=102};

I am using Eigen version 3.3.90 and MKL 2020.1.217-2.

The compilation code I am using is

```
g++ csbm_mu_parameter_mkl.cpp -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -O3 -mavx -mtune=intel -fopenmp -m64  -I /usr/include/mkl -o csbm_mu_parameter -L /usr/include/mkl/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lgomp -lpthread -ldl
```

I would appreciate if you can help me to understand what is going wrong with the compilation.

Comment: Please post a [mre] including which library versions (MKL and Eigen) and the compilation flags you are using.

Comment: You did not provide a [mre] yet (please read that link), but it looks like you included two BLAS libraries (gsl-cblas and mkl-cblas).